# Nightmare of installing and running Tensorflow in R Studio on windows 10

Tags: python, r, windows, tensorflow

Please, I have been having trouble for weeks now trying to install and run tensorflow and keras in R Studio. I have tried everything I can find online to no avail. I have anaconda installed on my system, do I need to uninstall it? After running this line of code:

```
install_tensorflow(method = "conda",version = "default", envname = "py3.6",
                   conda_python_version = "3.6",
                   extra_packages = c("matplotlib","numpy","pandas","scikit-learn"))
install_keras(method = "conda")
```

It says installation successful, but when I now run `tf$constant("Hellow Tensorflow")` I get the following error message:

```
Error: Installation of TensorFlow not found.

Python environments searched for 'tensorflow' package:
 C:\Users\IFEANYI\AppData\Local\r-miniconda\envs\r-reticulate\python.exe

You can install TensorFlow using the install_tensorflow() function.
```

I also try to install keras using:

```
install_keras(method = "conda")
install_keras(tensorflow = "default")
```

But I also get an error message:

```
Error in install_keras(method = "conda") : 
  You should call install_keras() only in a fresh R session that has not yet initialized Keras and TensorFlow (this is to avoid DLL in use errors during installation)
```

I also have reticulate installed in R Studio. I honestly do not know why it is such a task to install and run tensorflow in R for windows 10. I have been on it for weeks without any tangible headway. Please, as always I will be extremely grateful if someone can help me resolve this nagging issue

Comment: Please can someone be so kind as to give my issue a looking, thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

there have been significant changes to the installation pathway in the R package recently. Can you please try the following (in a fresh R session):

```
install.packages("keras")
reticulate::install_miniconda()
keras::install_keras()
```

If the above doesn't work, can you please file an issue: https://github.com/rstudio/keras/issues/new

Comment: @t-kalinowskiSorry, what should I do if I see **Error: Error creating conda environment 'r-reticulate' [exit code 1]** after running `reticulate::install_miniconda()`?

Answer (score 0):

If you are working in a project environment in RStudio, I suggest closing the project using **Close Project** option in the upper-right slider in RStudio. Make sure you have installed Python on your system and try the following codes (change Username based on the user name of your system):

```
library(keras)
library(tensorflow)
library(reticulate)
path_to_python <- "C:/Users/Username/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310"
virtualenv_create("r-reticulate", python = path_to_python)
install_tensorflow(envname = "r-reticulate")
install_keras(envname = "r-reticulate")
use_virtualenv("r-reticulate")
```

I hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

I have a related issue in installing tensorflow and keras. When running tensorflow:install_tensorflow R studio simply crashes after a while. I have tried everything, I do not really know what else to do.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35139230)